# Windows 10 brightness bug Lenovo G475

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, lenovo-laptop

I just upgraded my laptop from windows 7 to windows 10 home, But the brightness won't change using the fn shortcut key and the windows brightness slider, but when changing the power plan in lenovo energy cut application, the brightness changes! how to fix this problem so that the fn shortcut key and windows brightness slider would also work. I Tried reinstalling video drivers and other drivers as well.

Comment: Do the FN keys work at all?

Comment: yes it does work, i can still use it for the sound and other special keys

Answer (score 0):

You should try installing the [Lenovo Energy Management](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/lenovo-g-series-laptops/lenovo-g475-notebook/downloads/DS030850)

Even if this is for Windows 8 it should work in Windows 10.

Comment: I've also tried installing that, but still the brightness wont change, it only works on the old lenovo energy cut, but the fn key shortcut doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

I fixed with this guide, 
It works, the screen suddenly goes black,
when this happens don't panic, is normal, just wait and will go back seconds later.
when restart it changes the screen resolution to 1024x768, if this is your resolution don't care, if isn't, don't use this method...
http://www.redmondpie.com/fix-windows-10-brightness-control-not-working-issue-heres-how-guide/

Comment: Its good to link back to original post but important to post essential parts of the answer if you would like your answer to considered good